# upgrading substrate node from Polkadot 0.9.28 to 0.9.40

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, pallet-contracts, json-rpc

I have a `substrate node` of `Polkadot 0.9.28`.  It is customised to enable contracts, and I have enabled the contract and runtime pallets. The tutorial I worked on is no more available in substrate docs. I have updated my Ink version from `3 to 4`. Now while working with the nodejs to deploy the contract on the chain I am facing issues. I have updated my `@polkadot/api` and `@polkadot/api-contrat packages`. I don't know why the development does not work. Hence I would like to update Polakdot to a new version while retaining the features of **`contract-pallet`** and **`runtime-pallet`**. Is there a way to update it?

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases according to me in your case:

- If you haven't done any changes in the contracts pallet or any other pallet than you are good to go with a runtime upgrade from `0.9.28` -> `0.9.40` using  the tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/maintain/runtime-upgrades/.
- But if there are some changes in your `contracts pallet` than you need to apply those changes in `0.9.40` and do the runtime upgrade.
- But if there are some breaking changes than you need to a storage migration with the runtime upgrade for that you can follow https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/storage-migrations/.

After identifying what you require for your case, you can once try it on development mode are make a [private network](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/simulate-network/) replicating your scenario to test it out first.